# Summing up values for a specific key in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I see the object on the below screenshot when i do `console.log(changes)`

```
{
    "dt": "2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "gradeName": "grade 3",
    "effectiveFrom": "2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "salary": "10000.0000",
    "salaryEffective": "2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "leaveDate": "2022-07-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "dailyRate": "328.77"
}
{
    "dt": "2022-07-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "gradeName": "grade 3",
    "effectiveFrom": "2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "salary": "10000.0000",
    "salaryEffective": "2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "leaveDate": "2022-07-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "dailyRate": "328.77"
}
```

What would be the right way to sum up salary values for a specific grade ? I am stuck on trying to figure out how to loop over the object in the first place. I tried,

```
for (const [index, [key, value]] of Object.entries(Object.entries(changes))) {
        console.log(`${index}: ${key} = ${value}`);
      }
```

where changes refers to the object.

I am seeing the below output in the console,

[image]

Comment: Can you please include JSON of the `changes` object instead of asking us to read the screenshot? It's pretty hard to read. Thanks!

Comment: @Zachiah included json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function sumBy(grade) {
  let sumSoFar = 0;
  for (const {gradeName, salary} of changes)
    if (gradeName === grade)
      sumSoFar += Number(salary);

  return sumSoFar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `reduce` to calculate the sum of all the salary values. Below is a example.

```js
const dummyArr = new Array(5).fill(5).map((val, ind) => ({
  salary: ind + 1
}));
console.log(dummyArr);

console.log(dummyArr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + parseFloat(curr.salary), 0));
```

Comment: not clear to me how i would sum up based on a specific key like the grade or any another key

Comment: so the reduce method takes two arguments a callback function and initial value ( here I have given it as 0 for initial value, that will be the value of prev on first try). meanwhile curr will contain the elements one by one (which here is a object so, I'm accessing the object and picking salary ) which will be summed up with prev value and this will be done for all the object values

Comment: that is clear but how will i get and sum salaries for only a particular grade. I do not want to sum up all salaries in the object but sum up based on another key value like gradeName i.e. sum of all salaries with grade3 only

Comment: You can use `filter` method on the array to first filter the result based on the grade you want and then use reduce over it. Just use filter on the dummyArr above something like this `dummyArr.filter(val=>val.grade==="grade1").reduce(....)`